# Verify user credentials without logging in with Java's JAAS security

Tags: security, jsf, jaas

I am developing a JSF 2 application running under JBOSS Wildfly, which utilizes Java's JAAS security mechanism.

Everything works as expected and I can login using the request.login(username, password) mechanism.

I also have a requirement to authorize a device (which I have implemented using cookies) as part of the login processs. The process I am trying to implement is as follows;

1. Validate username and password (but not log them in)
2. Check device authorization and redirect to the authorization process pages
   if not already authorized).
3. Login (if authorization is successful)

I don't want to log the user in unless they are authorized, and I don't want to go through the authorization process unless the username and password is correct.

So I need to verify the credentials are correct without actually logging the user in. I can do this manually via a database query, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this via JAAS.

Any ideas?
Rich

Comment: What do you mean by "without logging in"? Which is the specific step you want to avoid? Showing a logging form/popup? Retrieving its roles?

Comment: I don't want to perform a JAAS login (by calling request.login(username, password)) I would like to call something like request.checkCredentials(username, password) to get a boolean response as to whether the username and password are valid, but without actually logging them in. But checkCredentials() obviously doesn't exist - i was looking for similiar functionality from JAAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to check credentials in JAAS/JEE. However you might log in and immediately log out user:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
        .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
try {
    request.login(name, password);
    request.logout();
    isValid = true;
} catch (ServletException e) {
    isValid = false;
}
```

`ServletException` means that user is not valid (or other error occurred).

You can also use internal JBoss class `org.jboss.security.AuthenticationManager` and its `isValid(..)` method. See [example](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/PicketBoxAuthentication). But this binds you to JBoss AS/Wildfly.